# Find max and min values in a .json

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, d3.js

For a graph I'm trying to do with d3.js I need to set up the scales for the axis.

The data for the graph is stored in a Json file structured like so:

```
[{
    "id" : "AustraliaNewZealand" ,
    "year" : [1990,1992,1994,1993,1995,1996,1997,1998,1999,2000,2001,2002,2003,2004,2005,2006,2007,2008,2009,2010],
    "value":[477790,485825,487296,488885,502585,511718,526594,538967,550556,563572,577171,579126,591635,599216,604267,608954,615853,623685,618961,614920]
}, 
{
    "id":"CentralEurope",
    "year":[1990,1992,1994,1993,1995,1996,1997,1998,1999,2000,2001,2002,2003,2004,2005,2006,2007,2008,2009,2010],
    "value":[1548736,1334452,1313088,1283248,1314709,1360546,1343907,1285511,1237278,1251872,1244069,1233778,1284639,1297510,1317861,1359787,1396681,1361445,1278731,1343044]
}, 
{
    "id":"EasternEurope",
    "year":[1990,1992,1994,1993,1995,1996,1997,1998,1999,2000,2001,2002,2003,2004,2005,2006,2007,2008,2009,2010],
    "value":[4418516,3530464,3287987,2925644,2775181,2672238,2540975,2495036,2513372,2515375,2540796,2544848,2598148,2637682,2622241,2709974,2714204,2740248,2565213,2680226]
}, 
{
    "id":"NorthAmerica",
    "year":[1990,1992,1994,1993,1995,1996,1997,1998,1999,2000,2001,2002,2003,2004,2005,2006,2007,2008,2009,2010],
    "value":[6750754,6821412,6948829,7059001,7166869,7386971,7460485,7509719,7573562,7790060,7675762,7710685,7769154,7896824,7918461,7841686,7966277,7751508,7277713,7493948]
}, 
{
    "id":"WesternEurope",
    "year":[1990,1992,1994,1993,1995,1996,1997,1998,1999,2000,2001,2002,2003,2004,2005,2006,2007,2008,2009,2010],
    "value":[4365949,4290345,4222425,4221029,4264725,4353056,4290057,4310736,4251628,4260565,4306230,4278128,4333237,4337031,4305560,4267515,4209481,4125479,3841580,3924831]
}]
```

and what I'd like to do is to iterate between the various arrays nested to get the years and values minimum and maximum values, but I don't know how to get those values. I managed to get the values of a single array using:

```
var xScale = d3 .time.scale()
                .domain((d3.extent(dataset[0].year)))
                .range([margin*2, (width - margin)]);
var yScale = d3 .scale.linear()
                .domain([0, d3.max(dataset[0].value)])
                .range([(height - margin), margin]);
```

where `_dataset_` is the identifier of the callback function, but what I'd like to have is to get the minimum and maximum values between all the arrays (like for example min value is in array3 and max in array 1). I guess I should use a *for* cycle, but I don't know where I should put it and how to set it up to look in all the arrays.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's very fun if we use a little functional programming instead of `for` loops here:

```
d3.extent(dataset.reduce(function(a,b) { return a.concat(b.year) }, []))
```

You can do the same thing with the values.

Answer (score 1):

The Math functions `min` and `max` are really useful here if you use [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply):

```
function getMinMax(array, type) {
  var out = [];
  array.forEach(function(el) { return out.push.apply(out, el[type]); }, []);
  return { min: Math.min.apply(null, out), max: Math.max.apply(null, out) };
}

console.log(getMinMax(array, 'year')); // { min=1990, max=2010 }
console.log(getMinMax(array, 'value')); // { min=477790, max=7966277}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/andyuws/3FRr6/8/)

Comment: thanks, this works but returns the min and max for each array, maybe I wasn't clear in my question but I was trying to get the min and max values of the arrays combined, I'll try to make that work

Comment: Thanks for updating the answer! I marked as the correct one the one by homam just because it was faster (and his method doesn't involve any for loop which I didn't know was possible), but yeah thanks for the update :)

Answer (score 0):

Javascript now provides a [`flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) method on `Array`s which both flattens an array of arrays into a single array and applies a transforming function on each elements:

```
var [min, max] = d3.extent(dataset.flatMap(d => d.value));
```

For example:

```js
var input = [
  { id: "AustraliaNewZealand", value: [477790,485825,487296,488885,502585,511718,526594,538967,550556,563572,577171,579126,591635,599216,604267,608954,615853,623685,618961,614920] },
  { id: "CentralEurope",       value: [1548736,1334452,1313088,1283248,1314709,1360546,1343907,1285511,1237278,1251872,1244069,1233778,1284639,1297510,1317861,1359787,1396681,1361445,1278731,1343044] },
  { id: "EasternEurope",       value: [4418516,3530464,3287987,2925644,2775181,2672238,2540975,2495036,2513372,2515375,2540796,2544848,2598148,2637682,2622241,2709974,2714204,2740248,2565213,2680226] }
];

var [min, max] = d3.extent(input.flatMap(d => d.value));

console.log(min);
console.log(max);
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-array.v2.min.js"></script>
```